# How may I show $x!$ grows faster than $(x+1)^{n-1}$

Tags: limits, functions

I am trying to show that the factorial function grows faster than its respective power function.
I started by define $f(x) = \frac {x!} {x^{n}}$ and then looked at $\frac {f(x+1)} {f(x)}$ and got $\frac {x^n} {(x+1)^{(n-1)}}$ and took the limit as n goes to infinity, and got $0$.

If I recall, that's inconclusive, yes?

Note: As I'm typing this, I feel that maybe I should have taken the limit as x goes to infinity, since I am trying to show the argument of $x$ grows.

Comment: Is $n$ a constant or a variable in this function?

Comment: What's $x!?$ Do you know what's 1.243!?

Comment: what is $n$ in your function $f(x)$?

Comment: @Ruzayqat 1.1289.. or, for example, just 1. Its nowhere said that $f: \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$. But in both know cases(Г-function and just $\mathbb{N}\mapsto \mathbb{N}$ its true)

Comment: "Than its respective power function" what do you mean be that?

Comment: Well, @EzWin, yeah, but I believe the word "factorial" is reserved to positive integers and 0. So I do not think he meant the gamma function

Comment: @Arthur wolfram counts '!' sign as gamma function. The only other case could work here if its $n!$, not $x!$, which is true again.

Comment: Yes, I should have been more clear, my apologies. I am new here.
I am trying to show that $x!$ grows faster than $x^k$

Answer (score 2):

Using the Stirling approximation and for some $0< c< 1$ we have
$$
x!\approx \sqrt{2\pi x}\left(\frac{x}{e}\right)^x
$$
so that
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x!}{(x+1)^{n-1}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{2\pi x}\left(\frac{x}{e}\right)^x}{(x+1)^{n-1}}\ge\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x}{e}\right)^{x-n+1}\left(\frac{x}{e(x+1)}\right)^{n-1}\ge\lim_{x\to\infty}c\left(\frac{x}{e}\right)^{x-n+1}=\infty.
$$